# getting error whenever try to deploy backend with cdk via gitlab , in local it will works as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, gitlab, serverless, aws-cdk

I am trying to deploy backend serverless resources with CDK in AWS cloud but getting errors while deploying things via GitLab build.
trying with a local visual studio it works fine.

error is below :

```
$ npm run deploy-backend
> ui-dashboard-infra@0.0.0 deploy-backend /builds/project/control-panel/infra
> cdk deploy --app 'ts-node stacks/backend' --all --require-approval never
Bundling asset dashboard-A/restFunctionFallbackus-east-1/Code/Stage...
/builds/project/control-panel/infra/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/asset-staging.ts:398
      throw new Error(`Failed to bundle asset ${this.node.path}, bundle output is located at ${bundleErrorDir}: ${err}`);
            ^
Error: Failed to bundle asset dashboard-A/restFunctionFallbackus-east-1/Code/Stage, bundle output is located at /builds/project/control-panel/infra/cdk.out/bundling-temp-4607286efdd890681baca6f8a5d9b9b32929fa84e9947500fbe203e5b5d06a0f-error: Error: spawnSync bash ENOENT
    at AssetStaging.bundle (/builds/project/control-panel/infra/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/asset-staging.ts:398:13)
    at AssetStaging.stageByBundling (/builds/project/control-panel/infra/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/asset-staging.ts:246:10)
    at stageThisAsset (/builds/project/control-panel/infra/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/asset-staging.ts:137:35)
    at Cache.obtain (/builds/project/control-panel/infra/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/private/cache.ts:24:13)
    at new AssetStaging (/builds/project/control-panel/infra/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/asset-staging.ts:162:44)
    at new Asset (/builds/project/control-panel/infra/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-s3-assets/lib/asset.ts:68:21)
    at AssetCode.bind (/builds/project/control-panel/infra/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-lambda/lib/code.ts:180:20)
 
Subprocess exited with error 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ui-dashboard-infra@0.0.0 deploy-backend: `cdk deploy --app 'ts-node stacks/backend' --all --require-approval never`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ui-dashboard-infra@0.0.0 deploy-backend script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-08-10T08_29_17_449Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Do you get the same error if you try to execute from outside of npm context? ( `$(npm bin)/cdk deploy --app 'ts-node stacks/backend' --all --require-approval never` )

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error as you. In my case, the issue was that I had `esbuild` installed as a dependency in the CDK folder, but not in the folder of my Lambda function.

**I was able to fix the issue by installing `esbuild` as a dev dependency in my Lambda function folder.** If you don't want to do that, you can also install it globally in your pipeline by adding the command `npm i -g esbuild` to your pipeline (consider pinning it to a particular version ie. `npm i -g esbuild@x.y.z`).

No idea why it was working locally without esbuild installed in the function folder, but then broke when doing the same thing in a Gitlab pipeline… I didn't have esbuild installed globally on my local machine or anything.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced a similar kind of issue, and the problem is that there is a bug in cdk versions prior to the once released before 25th Feb 2021.

For that, please make sure either you are using the latest version of cdk, or you **DO NOT HAVE ANY WHITE SPACES IN YOUR FILE PATHNAME** (any directory name having space or your username that has a space might cause this problem). Once I removed the white spaces from the pathname, everything started to work as expected.